# Create new column based on 2 reference string columns

Tags: r, string, if-statement, dplyr

**Problem**

I have 2 dataframes, a reference dataframe `ref_df` and a test dataframe `test_df`. The reference dataframe was made to consist of 2 columns (strings): `reference_A` and `reference_B` for which I would like to create a new column, in my `test_df` dataframe to state that if both strings columns `test_A` and `test_B`  match `reference_A` and `reference_B`, then "Pass", else "Fail".

---

**Example Data**

reference dataframe

```
ref_df <- data.frame(
  reference_A = c("ABC","HIJ","NOP","TUV"),
  reference_B = c("DEF","KLM","QRS","WXY")
)

ref_df

  reference_A reference_B
1         ABC         DEF
2         HIJ         KLM
3         NOP         QRS
4         TUV         WXY
```

test_df dataframe

```
test_df <- data.frame(
  sample = c(1,2,3,4,5,6),
  test_A = c("ABC","HII","NOP","TUV","TUS","KJF"),
  test_B = c("DEF","KLM","QRR","WXY","WXZ", "KLM")
)

test_df

  sample test_A test_B
1      1    ABC    DEF
2      2    HII    KLM
3      3    NOP    QRR
4      4    TUV    WXY
5      5    TUS    WXZ
6      6    KJF    KLM
```

---

**Desired Solution**

```
test_qc

  sample test_A test_B status
1      1    ABC    DEF Pass
2      2    HII    KLM Fail
3      3    NOP    QRR Fail
4      4    TUV    WXY Pass
5      5    TUS    WXZ Fail
6      6    KJF    KLM Fail
```

---

**Failed Attempt**

```
test_qc <- test_df %>% 
  select(test_A, test_B) %>% 
  mutate(status = 
           ifelse(test_A == ref_df$reference_A & test_B == ref_df$reference_B, 
                  "Pass", "Fail"))
```

```
Warning messages:
1: Problem with `mutate()` input `status`.
ℹ longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
ℹ Input `status` is `ifelse(...)`. 
2: In test_A == reference$reference_A :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
3: Problem with `mutate()` input `status`.
ℹ longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
ℹ Input `status` is `ifelse(...)`. 
4: In test_B == reference$reference_B :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
library(dplyr)

ref_df$temp <- 1
 
test_df %>% left_join(ref_df, by =c("test_A" = "reference_A", "test_B" = "reference_B"))%>% mutate(status = if_else(is.na(temp), "Fail", "Pass")) %>% select(-temp)

  sample test_A test_B status
1      1    ABC    DEF   Pass
2      2    HII    KLM   Fail
3      3    NOP    QRR   Fail
4      4    TUV    WXY   Pass
5      5    TUS    WXZ   Fail
6      6    KJF    KLM   Fail
```

Answer (score 1):

You can `paste` the keys to together to see if there is a match and assign `'Pass'` and `'Fail'` accordingly.

```
transform(test_df, status = ifelse(paste(test_A, test_B) %in% 
                 paste(ref_df$reference_A, ref_df$reference_B), 'Pass', 'Fail'))

#  sample test_A test_B status
#1      1    ABC    DEF   Pass
#2      2    HII    KLM   Fail
#3      3    NOP    QRR   Fail
#4      4    TUV    WXY   Pass
#5      5    TUS    WXZ   Fail
#6      6    KJF    KLM   Fail
```

Can also be written in `dplyr` :

```
library(dplyr)
test_df %>%
  mutate(status = if_else(paste(test_A, test_B) %in% 
             paste(ref_df$reference_A, ref_df$reference_B), 'Pass', 'Fail'))
```

Comment: Always elegant @Ronak Shah!